# Euclidean distance formula in higher dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, metric-spaces

I’m just wondering what is the intuition regarding the extension of this theorem into higher dimensions. For $n = 4$, I imagine that since the last three dimensions were defined in the way they were, we just will “call” the Euclidean distance in $4D$ the formula they have. At this point it’s not modelling physical space anymore is it, it is just an equation that $4$ numbers are used in that we treat as “distance” in $4D$. (Closest thing we could possibly get / define) .

Comment: Check this post for some hints: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398405/is-the-distance-formula-applicable-for-4-dimensional-coordinate-system-if-yes

Comment: Well, your two points live on a line in whatever dimensional space, and the notion of distance you get that way has to be the same as what you'd get on the line.  For instance, the distance between $(1,2,0,0)$ and $(3,4,0,0)$ is $\sqrt {(3-1)^2+(4-2)^2}$, just as it would be if you ignored the last two coordinates.

Comment: @lulu we can't use only lines to justify Euclidean metric, as any norm will give us a metric where distance on a line restricts to distance from $\mathbb R$.  We need to consider planes as in Qiaochu Yuan's answer.  Equivalently, we need a notion of angle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! Let me set it up more precisely as follows: we consider two vectors $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and we'd like to choose a way to measure the distance between them. We know that when $n = 2, 3$ we have the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) and we'd like to know what, if anything, justifies the use of the Euclidean distance when $n \ge 4$.

First of all, if you believe that the Euclidean distance for $n = 2, 3$ is justified by our living in an (approximately) Euclidean 3D space, then the answer is "nothing," since we don't live in a 4D or higher Euclidean space. In fact there are many different ways to measure distances between vectors, such as the [$\ell^p$ norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions), and different ones are suitable for different purposes. The Euclidean distance here corresponds to $p = 2$ but $p = 1$ and $p = \infty$ are also very common and useful choices.

On the other hand, here is a positive result. Let's say you want the distance to have the following properties, which ought to look pretty reasonable, and are all true of the Euclidean distance:

1. It is determined by some non-negative function $\| v - w \| \ge 0$ of the difference between $v$ and $w$ (this is equivalent to requiring that it be invariant under translation).
2. The function $v \mapsto \| v \|$ is absolutely homogeneous in the sense that if $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar then $\| cv \| = |c| \| v \|$ where $|c|$ is the usual absolute value.
3. $\| v \|$ satisfies the triangle inequality $\| v + w \| \le \| v \| + \| w \|$ and the nondegeneracy axiom that if $\| v \| = 0$ then $v = 0$. These three conditions say that $\| - \|$ is a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)), and imply that $\| v - w \|$ is a (particularly nice) [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space).
4. The **[parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law)** holds: $\| v \|^2 + \| w \|^2 = \frac{ \| v + w \|^2 + \| v - w \|^2}{2}$.

Then it turns out that $\| v - w \|$ must be the Euclidean distance up to a change of coordinates! This follows from a classic argument involving the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#Normed_vector_spaces_satisfying_the_parallelogram_law).

Note that this last condition only involves two vectors at a time, so it is really a condition on how the distance behaves when restricted to the plane containing $0, v, w$. So the significance of this result is that the Euclidean distance on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is determined (up to a change of coordinates) by 1) being induced by a norm, and 2) restricting to the Euclidean distance (up to a change of coordinates) on every plane through the origin.